# Order By Case String Not Working

Tags: mysql, group-by, case

I am trying to get my SQL search to work. What I am looking for is a search result that pulls information based on either a company's name or their stock trading ticker. If one would to type in **M**, I would expect:

```
MAT  - Mattel
MFST - Microsoft
MA   - MasterCard
MDLZ - Mondelez
MON  - Monsanto
```

It queries the "ticker" just fine, but how would I get it to allow both? If I search **MO** instead of "M", I would expect to see this:

```
MON  - Monsanto
MDLZ - Mondelez
```

I want it to give bias towards the "ticker", but also query the name if it is like the search term. Here is my code:

```
SELECT `stock_id`, `stock_ticker`, `stock_simpleName` 
FROM `stocks` 
WHERE `stock_ticker` = 'M' 
GROUP BY `stock_ticker`, `stock_simpleName` 
ORDER BY CASE  
    WHEN `stock_ticker` LIKE 'M%' THEN 1 
    WHEN `stock_simpleName` LIKE 'M%' THEN 2 
    ELSE 3 
END 
LIMIT 5
```

I wrote a different query that easily pulled the "ticker" alone, but trying to query them both with bias towards one of the columns like stated above seems to be a bit difficult. My AJAX returns an error which obviously means it's returning a PHP error rather than the data that should be requested.

Is there a tweak for this to get it to work?

Comment: Test your query in commandline or orther client with interactive response before putting it to php, that way you know where the error is.

Comment: It is legal syntax, so it is a logic error. So hooray for me, now I how to be logical with it. But I am still tweaking it, every little bit.

Comment: Then it becomes a question about php and your code if the AJAX call is giving you some error. But about the query - you only check the `stock_ticker` in the WHERE clause so you do not get any rows matching only on `stock_simpleName`.

Answer (score 1):

So I tweaked the code a bit by testing it in phpMyAdmin, and this is what worked:

```
SELECT `stock_id`, `stock_ticker`, `stock_simpleName` 
FROM `stocks` 
GROUP BY `stock_ticker`, `stock_simpleName` 
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN `stock_ticker` LIKE 'MO%' THEN 1 
    WHEN `stock_simpleName` LIKE 'MO%' THEN 2 
    ELSE 3 
END 
LIMIT 5
```

I just removed the `WHERE` Statement entirely. It works exactly like I needed it to. I thought `WHERE` was always required for any statement that succeeds the `FROM table.column` part of the query. `

Comment: Why do you need the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: You can add a `WHERE stock_ticker LIKE 'MO%'  OR stock_simpleName LIKE 'MO%'`, if you want only those results.

Comment: I want the bias though. I want it to look for the ticker first then the simpleName.

Comment: I meant ... and keep the `ORDER BY CASE ...` But really, the `GROUP BY` is probably useless, if not harmful. Do you have rows with same exact stock ticker and simpleName?

Answer (score 0):

Build a table specifically for this lookup:

```
CREATE TABLE Lookup (
    name VARCHAR(22) NOT NULL,
    precedence TINYINT NOT NULL,  -- replaces your CASE: 1 for ticker; 2 for simpleName
    stock_id ... NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (name),  -- for the uniqueness
    INDEX(stock_id)   -- for maintenance
) ENGINE=InnoDB -- to get clustering on name
```

Then insert 1 or 2 (maybe more?) rows for each stock.

Fetching:

```
SELECT stock_id
    FROM Lookup
    WHERE name LIKE 'MO%'   -- filled in dynamically
    ORDER BY precedence, name
    LIMIT 5;
```

This will be faster, avoids ticker:simpleName dups, etc.